VM's have no internet when using OPNsense VM until all service reloaded
I am running Proxmox on a single, non-clustered host with a 4-port Broadcom network card (It's a Dell R730). I have one vmbr0 (linux bridge) set up for port 1, which is directly connected to my router for internet connection to VMs. I have a vmbr1 set up but not attached to any interface, set to a private IP address of 192.168.4.1. I then have a VM running OPNsense, with the WAN interface set up on vmbr0 and the LAN interface set up on vmbr1. I then have other virtual machines which are directly connected to vmbr1, effectively adding them to a separated private network.
The problem I am having is whenever I start the VM's, for whatever reason the VM's attached to the virtual router do not have internet connection until after I reload all services on OPNsense. When I try to ping the virtual router from the VM, it can ping it just fine with no issues. When trying to ping the VM from the virtual router, OPNsense cannot ping it.
I can verify that DHCP is set up correctly. And while I do currently have firewall rules in place, this problem occurs even with a fresh, default config with no rules in place.
Why is this happening, and how can I work around it if there is no fix?
EDIT: I had another port available ony NIC, and a separate NIC card so I figured I'd try something different - I hooked the LAN interface of the router VM to a free NIC port, and attached that NIC to a separate switch. I then plugged the other NIC into the switch, and set up another Linux bridge for that. My line of thinking was there is no issue with Proxmox VMs getting internet from my other routers that are physical, so I figured this would be no different. It did not fix the problem and exhibits the same issues. I'm about to switch to pfSense, see if that fixes it. (I have already factory reset twice, that is not the solution).
EDIT 2: pfSense does not fix the problem, whatever the issue is it does not seem to be coming from OPNsense itself and is instead someting with Proxmox.

While I did not find a super definitive "This is the exact thing that fixed this", I have resolved this problem.
First, I found a video from the Home Network Guy called "Virtualizing OPNsense on Proxmox as your primary router" And watched what he did. Firstly I just fully deleted all my network bridges and started again. I set BOTH the network bridges and the interfaces attached to auto start. Double click on your network interface/network bridge, and check the "Autostart" checkbox. I also ran the Proxmox VE Post-Installation Script, which can be found here. Copy/Paste the bash command into the Shell tab on your Proxmox VE node (or all nodes if you have more than one) and hit enter. Make sure to read the prompts! (The script likely did not fix the problem, but it allowed me to update Proxmox and may have at least helped.
Afterwards I disabled Proxmox's firewall on ALL interfaces/bridges running off the virtual router by going to the hardware section of each virtual machine, double clicking the network interfaces, and unchecking the "Firewall" option. And finally, I made sure the virtual router fully started BEFORE the other machines booted up. (Set you start/shutdown order to "1" and then set no delay on the Router, then set all other VM's using the router to
"2" on boot order and set a 60 second delay. Overkill maybe, but it prevents any issues.)
Since then, the router has just worked and I have not experienced any issues. Please anyone who finds this post with the same issue, let me know if this helps!
